# Moment JS if statement not working check before time

Tags: javascript, if-statement, momentjs

The code inside of the IF Statement works outside of it and adds 15 Minutes as expected but doesn't change anything inside of the IF Statement

New to coding and have been researching for hours and can't get around this so any input would be great thanks

```
function calTime() {
  var format = "HH:mm";  
  var hour = document.getElementById('hourinput').value;
  var mins = document.getElementById('mininput').value;
  var bt = moment().add(hour,'h').add(mins, 'm').format(format);

  if (moment(bt, "HH:mm").isAfter('10:15', "HH:mm")){
    bt = moment(bt, "HH:mm").add(15, 'm').format(format);
  }
  else {

  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = bt;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get inside `else`? The logical explanation why your line inside the `if` block doesn't work, it is because it is not invoked. Add a `console.log` inside the `else` block, and check your condition ;)

Comment: tried that and it seems to be something wrong with the condition of the `if` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should send a moment to isAfter function the correct way is this

```
function calTime(hour, mins) {
  var format = "HH:mm";  
  var bt = moment().add(hour,'h').add(mins, 'm');
  if (bt.isAfter(moment('10:15', "HH:mm"))){
     bt = bt.add(15, 'm');
  }

   return bt.format(format);
 }
```

and parsing the string for moment is hard so format on last line.